# APEX: Column Sum

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have table "ZM" like this

```
ZM_ID |COSTS
10000 |200
10001 |700
10002 |100
10003 |500
10004 |100
```

On page 18 I have item `:P18_ZM_ID`:

I get a comma-separated list of the `am_id` values I am interested in

```
select listagg (ZM_ID, ',') within group (order by ZM_ID) as ZM_ID  
  from EST_ZM  
 where EST_ID = :P18_EST_ID
```

This returns a value like "10000,10002,10004" into my `:P18_ZAM_ID` item

Now, I want sum costs where `ZM_ID = :P18_ZM_ID`

I tried something like

```
select SUM(Costs)  
  from ZM 
 where ZM_ID IN (:P18_ZAM_ID)
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you need to do this in two steps?  It would seem to make more sense (and I'm assuming that you have two different tables `zm` and `est_zm` given that your queries have two different table names-- the query can be simplified if there is really only one `zm` table)

```
SELECT sum(costs)
  FROM zm
 WHERE zm_id IN (SELECT zm_id
                   FROM est_zm
                  WHERE est_id = :p18_est_id)
```

The reason that your code isn't working is that there is a huge difference between the string `1,2,3` which is a single string that happens to have two commas and a list of values.  If you use a comma-separated string in an `IN` query, it will be treated as a single scalar value rather than multiple individual elements.  You could take the comma-separated string, parse it into a collection that has multiple elements, and then use that collection in your query.  But then you'd be taking data from a query, aggregating it into a single string, de-aggregating it into a collection, and then sending it back to the SQL engine which would generally be way more complicated than you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply.